# The function integrated over the two-sphere is smooth in the radial parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Define the function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$ h(w) = \int_{S^2} d\Omega(\hat{n})\,f(\sqrt{|w|}\, \hat{n}) $$
where $d\Omega(\hat{n})$ is the standard measure on two-dimensional sphere.

That is, in $\theta$, $\phi$ coordinates $\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$, $\hat{n}(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$) and
$$ h(w) = \int_{0}^\pi d \theta\int_0^{2\pi} d \phi~~ f(\sqrt{|w|}(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)). $$

Is it true that $h$ is smooth everywhere? 
This statement is certainly true if $f$ is polynomial (terms containing odd powers of $\sqrt{|w|}$ vanish after integration).